# How can I build framework without including needed framework?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frameworks

This question is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360716/meta-framework-constants-file).

TL;DR: I'm breaking down my code into frameworks and created a meta-framework that holds code (mostly constants and strings) that will be used in all my frameworks.

Now, I need to build the frameworks but I don't want to include the meta-framework on each one of them, as that will cause unnecessary code bloat. How can I make my frameworks aware of the meta-framework so I can test them quickly? Don't forget that they will all be included on the final application, so no sense in including a copy of the meta-framework on each framework I create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make your sub-frameworks **only link** to your meta-framework, by **not adding** the meta-framework to your sub-frameworks' copy files build phases.
This way you end up with **no duplicate code or resources**.

Then for including one of your sub-frameworks into an app (bundle, whatever) do the following:

1. **Link** project target to both, your **sub-frameworks** and your **meta-framework**.
2. Add "**Copy (Framework) Files**" **build phase** to project if none exists yet.
3. Add both, your **sub-frameworks** and your **meta-framework** to said **build phase**.
4. Optionally you might also want to add all the projects, that your project depends on, as dependencies. (For your sub-projects that would be your meta-project, and for your app that would be your sub-projects.)
5. ...
6. Profit.

This is basically what I do in my *DLAppKit.framework*, which relies on my *DLFoundationKit.framework* and in all apps that use *DLAppKit.framework*.

[image]

Comment: This sort of helped me. I had linked the sub-framework to the release version of the meta-framework but it would always say it couldn't find the framework. Then I dragged the meta-framework project into the sub-framework project and, voila, it builds perfectly.

Comment: Congrats then! This took me a while myself, back then ;) Frameworks can be quite tricky, especially when it comes to loading/install paths, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of this answer I'm going to assume that you're building standard, run-of-the-mill Frameworks using the built-in Xcode targets.  If that's the case, then your framework contain dynamic libraries, most likely as .dylib files.  Any code that links against such a framework won't incorporate the code from the contained library at compile time, it will load the framework and resolve symbols at runtime.

The upshot of this is that you needn't worry about code bloat; link away!  If your child frameworks depend on symbols defined in your parent framework then you'll need to link them to the parent framework.  In some cases you can play with Objective-C metaprogramming in horrific ways to get around including frameworks directly, but probably not in this case if you're including mostly constants and strings.